# How to convert a string to float number without knowing locale?

Tags: python

How to convert a string to float number without knowing locale?

For example:

```
str_num1 = "1,9"
str_num2 = "1.9"
```

Which conversion would work in both cases? I can probably use `replace`, but, as I said, I don't know locale.

Comment: What are the *possible* inputs…? May a comma/period be used for *thousand separators* as well? If not: just replace all `,` with `.` and then `float()` it.

Comment: If you don't know the locale, *find out*. Not knowing the locale means you don't know if `'1,900'` is `1.9` or `1900`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Basically I only have values between 0 and 1. Do you suggest to do something like `if "," in str_num: str_num.replace(",",".")`. If so, how can I know that "," should be replaced by ".", if I don't know locale?

Comment: if the values are only between 0 and 1 why does it matter ?

Comment: Why do you need to know the locale? Just do `float(n.replace(',', '.'))`. If there's no `,` in the string, then nothing will be replaced and you'll parse the original string. If there *is* a `,` in the string, it'll be replaced by `.` and then parsed by float. If your input is really that limited, there's basically no way for this to go wrong.

Comment: @tomgalpin: It refers to the first comment, when a person asked me about thousand separators.

Comment: @deceze: But what if it should be `float(n.replace('.', ','))` instead of `float(n.replace(',', '.'))`? Therefore I should know locale.

Comment: It should never be that, since you want to construct a valid *Python float literal*, and Python only accepts `.` as decimal separator, regardless of any locale.

Comment: @deceze: Ah, ok. I didn't know it. This was my main doubt:)